Build failed with 'invalid source release: 17' error while using connectivity_plus package in Flutter
I'm encountering a build failure when trying to compile my Flutter project. The error message indicates an invalid source release. Below are the details of the error and my development environment.
.
Ensured that all packages are up to date.
Cleaned the project using flutter clean and tried rebuilding.
Searched for similar issues but couldn't find a solution that worked.
Any help to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Environment:
Flutter version: 3.4.0
Dart SDK version: 3.22.0
connectivity_plus package version: ^6.0.1

java 19.0.2 2023-01-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 19.0.2+7-44)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.2+7-44, mixed mode, sharing)


The latest version of the connectivity_plus package is 6.0.3. The error message also mentions the background_fetch package. Have you run flutter pub outdated to check for other outdated dependencies?
